# Cannot create foreign key on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm trying to create a foreign key for a table named: Words_in_group, which holds all the words in a froup that the user creates.

I'm trying to refer the words to a table named: Words, which it's P-key is "Word".

Maybe this has something to do with the table "Words", that uses a composite key?

This is the script for creating the foreign key.

```
alter table "WORDS_IN_GROUP" add constraint
"WORDS_IN_GROUP_FK1" foreign key ("WORD") references "WORDS" ("WORD")
/
```

Here are the tables SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE  "WORDS_IN_GROUP"  (   "GROUP_CODE" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"WORD" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "WORDS_IN_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("GROUP_CODE") ENABLE  ) ;ALTER TABLE  "WORDS_IN_GROUP" ADD CONSTRAINT "WORDS_IN_GROUP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_CODE")
  REFERENCES  "GROUP_OF_WORDS" ("GROUP_CODE") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_WORDS_IN_GROUP"  before insert on "WORDS_IN_GROUP"                for each row  begin    if :NEW."GROUP_CODE" is null then 
select "GROUP_OF_WORDS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."GROUP_CODE" from dual; end if; end; /ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_WORDS_IN_GROUP" ENABLE;
***///////////

CREATE TABLE  "WORDS"  (    "WORD" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FILE_SN" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FILE_NAME" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"POSITION_NUM" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SECTION_NUM" NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"WORD_SECTION_POSITION" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "WORDS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("WORD", "FILE_SN") ENABLE ) ;
```

This is the error that I get:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: This is because a  primary key in Words table consist of 2 columns: word+file_sn, while your foreign key is single column: word

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read. I've edited the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key must always point to a unique key (either explicitly defined as such or defined as a primary key). As you noted, `word` in `words` is not necessarily unique - only the combination of `word, file_sn` is. You could either make `word` itself unique or add a `flie_sn` column to the `word_in_group` table and have a composite foreign key, whichever fits your application logic better.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik , let's say I would make `word` unique in the `words_in_group` table, will I still be able to hold the same `word` with a different  `Group_code` ? I guess this will rise a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You created composite Primary key for the table WORDS. But you just refer only single column in the table WORDS_IN_GROUP. This is not allowed.

You can refer only those column/group of columns which are unique(either enable Primary key/Unique key). If it is composite then you can create composite FK.